# bash: exit tool if nothing happens

Tags: bash, exit, host

The following script doesn't exit on terminal until I hit enter.

Need a script to exit automatically if nothing happens for some seconds. Or when all lines from the file is read.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
    
# Usage: ./tool.sh domains.txt

for addr in $(cat $1);do
        host $addr | grep "has address" | cut -d" " -f1,4 &
done
```

You can make a list of the following addresses to test the script:

```
google.com
yahoo.com
amazon.com
twitter.com
```

**Notice:** I don't want to remove the ampersand "&" from the script.

Thx.

Comment: try `nohup host $addr | grep "has address" | cut -d" " -f1,4 &`

Comment: @DigvijayS it didn't exit tool, and gave some errors in the output

Comment: nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout

Comment: I wouldn't consider this an "error message" .... Anyway, does it terminate, if you **do not** run it in the background? I find it strange, that you run the pipe in the **background**, but don't collect the output from the pipe anywhere.

Comment: @user1934428 "nohup" doesn't terminate the script.
I usually use ```tee output.txt``` on the terminal to collect the output, but not in the code.
If I omit the apmersand from the script it terminates with no problem even without using nohup. But I'd like to use ampersand to make to process faster.

Comment: Of course _nohup_ does not terminate it. Why do you think it does? You can use `exit` to terminate it, but it is terminated anyway when it reaches the end.

Comment: @sf31 : If you want to parallelize your processing, because your `host` commands take such a long time, you should put a `wait` in the end to wait for all your child processes to end.

Comment: I didn't think, in fact the other user did.
I added exit after ```done``` but nothing happens, and I have to hit ENTER to back to the terminal.

Comment: You mean I should replace ```&``` with ```wait``` ?
I did, but it seems bash doesn't recognize it!

Comment: @sf31 : Did you try to **trace** your script (set -x), to find, which command is possibly waiting for your stdin? What happens if you add a `</dev/null` to your `done` statement?

Comment: @sf31: No, this does not make sense. I just meant a `wait` at the end of the program, after the loop.

Comment: It worked! thanks!
I added the following: ```exit_code=$!``` and ```wait $exit_code``` with an echo command.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added `exit_code=$!` and `wait $exit_code` to my script to solve the problem.